# Check of a traffic light sequence using an array and if statements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have create a functioning automated traffic light sequence using an array and `if` statements. It all work correctly but I am wondering if there is anything more I can do to improve my code without changing to structure or way it works, so without the use of dictionary's etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title> Traffic Light</title>   

    <style>
        .rainbow {
            background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, red), color-stop(0.1, yellow), color-stop(0.2, green));
            background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
            color:transparent;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            background-clip: text;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body background="street.gif">
    <h1 class="rainbow">Traffic Light</h1>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="300"
    style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>


    <script>   

        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        ctx.rect(0, 0, 200, 300);
        ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
        ctx.fill();

        var colours=["red", "yellow", "green", "black","red yellow"];
        var current=colours[0];

        function offlight() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(95,50,40,10,12*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        function offlight1() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(95,150,40,10,12*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        function offlight2() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(95,250,40,10,12*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = "black";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        function drawLight1() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(95,50,40,10,12*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        function drawLight2() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(95,150,40,10,12*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        function drawLight3() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(95,250,40,10,12*Math.PI);
            ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        function changelight(){

            if (current==colours[0]){
                drawLight1();
                offlight1();
                offlight2();
                current=colours[4]
            } else if (current==colours[4]){
                drawLight1();
                drawLight2();
                offlight2();
                current=colours[2]
            } else if (current==colours[2]) {
                offlight();
                offlight1();
                drawLight3();
                current=colours[3]
            } else if (current==colours[3]){
                offlight();
                drawLight2();
                offlight2();
                current=colours[0]
            }

        }
        setInterval(changelight,1000);

    </script>

    <br><br>
    <button onclick="changelight()">Click</button>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. you don't ever use the strings in `colors`, but use them only as kind of id, what you are showing: an index would be sufficient, even the better solution.
2. you don't use the order in `colors` but instead you jump manually; sub-optimal, especially since you don't have any logic in there but just run a simple loop
3. And you repeat yourself excessively.

You have three lights, that are either on or off. To me this screams for the use of a bit-mask: The State is represented by an integer, and each bit of this integer represents one of the lights: it's either 1 or 0.

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(0, 0, 200, 300);
ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
ctx.fill();

//an array of the states, the code loops through
var activeLights = [0b100, 0b110, 0b001, 0b000, 0b010];
//var activeLights = [4, 6, 1, 0, 2];   //if your browser doesn't get the binary-notation
var currentIndex = 0;

function drawLight(index, color){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95,50+index*100,40,10,12*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function changelight(){
    var state = activeLights[currentIndex];

    //check the bit and draw the respective light
    drawLight(0, state & 0b100? "red": "black");
    drawLight(1, state & 0b010? "yellow": "black");
    drawLight(2, state & 0b001? "green": "black");      
    //drawLight(0, state & 4? "red": "black");
    //drawLight(1, state & 2? "yellow": "black");
    //drawLight(2, state & 1? "green": "black");

    //the loop
    if(++currentIndex === activeLights.length) currentIndex = 0;
}

setInterval(changelight, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your `<h1>` into the `<body>`.

What exactly are you looking for? File size (--> code reduction)? Speed optimization?

One simple thing would be using parameters to reduce code duplication:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.rect(0, 0, 200, 300);
ctx.fillStyle = "grey";
ctx.fill();

var colours = ["red", "yellow", "green", "black", "red yellow"];
var current = colours[0];

function offlight(a1) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, a1, 40, 10, 12 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawLight(a1, fillParam) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, a1, 40, 10, 12 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = fillParam;
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function changelight() {
    if (current == colours[0]) {
        drawLight(50, "red");
        offlight(150);
        offlight(250);
        current = colours[4]
    } else if (current == colours[4]) {
        drawLight(50, "red");
        drawLight(150, "yellow");
        offlight(250);
        current = colours[2]
    } else if (current == colours[2]) {
        offlight(50);
        offlight(150);
        drawLight(250, "green");
        current = colours[3]
    } else if (current == colours[3]) {
        offlight(50);
        drawLight(150, "yellow");
        offlight(250);
        current = colours[0]
    }

}
setInterval(changelight, 1000);
```

Do you ever use `colours[1]` ("yellow")?

You could also remove the whitespace and shorten variable and function names. Also, think about moving your JS into a seperate file.